# R: Logit Regression with Instrument Variable and Interaction Term

Tags: r, logistic-regression, interaction

I have a severe problem with R. I did not figure out how to run a logit regression with an instrument variable. 
The tricky thing is that I have 2 independent variables that work as an interaction term, but the instrument only works on one of the two independent variables. Further, I have a couple of Controls. 
I tried a couple of things with the AER ivreg package, but I could not figure out what I have to type in the regression command.

I would be so grateful if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is what you need:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-simple-instrumental-variables-problem/

The code in the post

```
library(AER)
library(lmtest)
data("CollegeDistance")
cd.d<-CollegeDistance
simple.ed.1s<- lm(education ~ distance,data=cd.d)
cd.d$ed.pred<- predict(simple.ed.1s)
simple.ed.2s<- lm(wage ~ urban + gender + ethnicity + unemp + ed.pred ,     data=cd.d)
simple.comp<- encomptest(wage ~ urban + gender + ethnicity + unemp + ed.pred , wage ~ urban + gender + ethnicity + unemp + education , data=cd.d)
1s.ftest<- encomptest(education ~ tuition + gender + ethnicity + urban ,     education ~ distance , data=cd.d)

library(arm)
coefplot(lm(wage ~ urban + gender + ethnicity + unemp + education,data=cd.d),vertical=FALSE,var.las=1,varnames=c("Education","Unemp","Hispanic","Af-am","Female","Urban","Education"))
coefplot(simple.ed.2s ,     vertical=FALSE,var.las=1,varnames=c("Education","Unemp","Hispanic","Af-am","Female","Urban","Education"))
```